# PHP/cURL Redirection

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Here is my problem

I want to post data to a page using curl, then to be redirected to the destination page without using the header function.

The call must be a post request.

I don't want to retrieve data on the call page.

Any solution ?

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/postdatahere.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($server_output == "OK") {
  header("Location: http://example.com/destination.php");
  die();
}
```

You can pickup the variables posted to this page, post them along to postdatahere.php, and still end up redirected to destination.php.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to handle it. One simple solution is to save the $data into session and retrieve the session data from the other file.

Another method is to create a form with those values and post the form using Javascript.